# What is the return value of an assignment in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, return-value, assignment-operator

What's the return value when I do an assignment?

For example, can I do this? (i.e. the assignment returns the value being assigned)

```
Dim a As Integer = 1
Dim b As Integer = 2
a = b = 3
```

The question came up when I wrote this code today:

```
Dim updates = GetUpdates()
While updates.Count > 0
    Foo.ApplyUpdates(updates)
    updates = GetUpdates()
End While
```

I kind of wish I could have written it this way...

```
While (updates = GetUpdates).Count > 0
    Foo.ApplyUpdates(updates)
End While
```

I know it's not as clean... (and I totally never declared `updates`) but it got me curious about how assignments work in .NET... is it a function with a return value? If so... what does it return?

**Edit**

I gave the first chunk of code a try. It looks like the compiler interprets it as assigning the result of comparing b and 3 to a... which is a compiler error of course.

And for the second code chunk, I get that the operator `=` is not defined for what ever type `updates` is... i.e. it thinks it's a comparison, not an assignment.

So to add to my question, why does it work this way? Is it just because vb.net overloads the symbol `=` with two meanings (assignment and comparison)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> about how assignment working in .NET.

This is actually about how assignment works in VB, not in .NET.

This does not work in VB.Net.  The [= Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41d8z008) in VB.Net merely "assigns the value on its right to the variable or property on its left."

> What's the return value when I do an assignment?

As seen in the above statement, the assignment operator *does not return a value in VB.Net*.

Note that this differs from other .NET languages.  For example, in C#, the assignment [= Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) does what you're describing, and "stores the value of its right-hand operand in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted by its left-hand operand and *returns the value as its result*."

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
a = b = 3
```

Note that, with `Option Strict` specified, this will actually be an error: "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Boolean' to 'Integer'."

This is because VB.Net sees this as two operations - it's basically trying to do:

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

Dim temp as Boolean
temp = (b = 3)
a = temp
```

> So to add to my question, why does it work this way? Is it just because vb.net overloads the symbol = with two meanings (assignment and comparison)?

Well, it's how the language was designed.  I suspect that you are correct, though, and since the same operator (=) is used as an assignment and a comparison is why VB was made this way.  However, the original VB language was this way, and to keep the syntax for VB.Net the same (or as close as possible), I suspect this behavior was carried forward.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Basic `a = b = 3` translates to something somewhat unexpected. Since VB doesn't have the `==` operator and instead uses `=` for both assignments and equality comparision, the above expression comes down to the following:

```
If b = 3 Then
    a = True
Else
    a = False
End If
```